# Best way for insert data (data type image )

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have use  query  fir insert ( insert into )
Other table other database table inclusive  (data type image ) is size table 150 Gb
 Now fast way for  insert
sql server 2014

Comment: You have provided no information by which to answer this question, and barely enough for a comment.

Comment: Questions not clear, and you have to show us what you do so far

Answer (score 1):

i use this for insert 500,000,000 rows from a table to another table in another database .

```
    declare @counter int=100
    while 1=1
    begin
        set @counter=@counter-1
        declare @maxid long=isnull((select top(1) id from destinationTable),0)
        insert into destinationTable 
           select top(50000) * from sourceTable where id>@maxid 
        if @@rowcount=0 or @counter<0
           break
    end
```

50000 has been selected after test Several numbers . it is best for this table .
for another table this number is 500000 , it depends on the table.

**tip**

- my source database was alive.
- destination database in a weak
- @counter is for avoid grow up log file
- this query run as job

i think if your databases is not alive , you have more choices